# Django testing user model fails but it works in the browser

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am new to testing and am trying to run the following tests but I get a *404 assertion error* because the method that tries to reverse the url cannot find the **category** that had been created in the **setUp** method. I can create **categories** in the browser using the **superuser** with no problem and the url responds with 200 status. Could you help me understand what I am doing wrong?

**Test:**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from cataloger.models import Category

class CatalogerCategoriesTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
       tom = User.objects.create_user(username="tom", password="1234567")
       Category.objects.create(name="cell phone", 
                            description="current cell phone types in the market.",
                            created_by=tom)

    def test_category_page_success_status_code(self):
       url = reverse('category_items', kwargs={'pk': 1})
       response = self.client.get(url)
       self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

**Fail:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/cataloger/tests_categories.py", line 48, in test_category_page_success_status_code
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200
```

**Models:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="categories")
```

**Views:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from cataloger.models import Category

def category_items(request, pk):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'category_items.html', {'category': category})
```

**urls:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^cataloger/$', views.cataloger, name='cataloger'),
        url(r'^cataloger/categories/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.category_items, name='category_items')
    ]
```

Comment: Please post urls.py

Comment: @Ykh I have added the urls.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pk` of the object might not always be `1` depending upon the test structure and DB. The `pk` of the `Category` instance should be used explicitly.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from cataloger.models import Category

class CatalogerCategoriesTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        tom = User.objects.create_user(username="tom", password="1234567")
        self.category = Category.objects.create(
            name="cell phone", 
            description="current cell phone types in the market.",
            created_by=tom
        )

    def test_category_page_success_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('category_items', kwargs={'pk': self.category.pk})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: thank you! it worked. I just had to do a minor edit to "self.category" attribute of the "setUp" method.

Answer (score 1):

@Stuart Dines explains very well. You should match pk for urls.

Or if you just want to know that model instance created well, just try `self.assertIsInstance(...)`

```
def setUp(self):
   tom = User.objects.create_user(username="tom", password="1234567")
   category = Category.objects.create(name="cell phone", 
                        description="current cell phone types in the market.",
                        created_by=tom)

def test_if_category_instance_made(self):
    self.assertIsInstance(self.category, Category)
```

> Also I recommend [model mommy](https://github.com/vandersonmota/model_mommy) for easy testing django models. It automatically generate random model (also put test data possible) and make really easy to testing your model!

This is example using model_mommy for your test code

```
from model_mommy import mommy

class CatalogerCategoriesTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.tom = mommy.make("User")
        self.category = mommy.make("Category", user=self.user)

    def test_if_category_instance_made(self):
        self.assertIsInstance(self.category, Category)

    def test_category_page_success_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('category_items', kwargs={'pk': self.category.pk})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: thanks for recommending this library. I was looking for something that resembles FactoryGirl in RoR.